# If a proper ideal contains some power of a maximal ideal then the maximal ideal is the only prime ideal that contains the ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and $\mathfrak{m}\subset R$ be a maximal ideal. Show that if $I\subset R$ is a proper ideal containing $\mathfrak{m}^n$ for some $n\geq 1$, then $\mathfrak{m}$ is the unique prime ideal containing $I$.

This question was asked in a recent exam that i appeared, but could not solve it. Any hints would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

What role does $n$ play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be a prime ideal containing $I$. Since $m^n \subseteq I$, $m^n \subseteq p$. This implies $m \subseteq p$. Since $m$ is maximal $m = p$.

Comment: Ahh! it was so tricky! Thank you alot

Comment: Dear @User101 Quick question: what part was tricky? I'm asking this as a serious question because I'm unsure of your background. Regards.

Comment: Dear @rschwieb Dummit-foote's definition of prime ideal(sec 7.4) for commutative ring is: $P\neq R$ and $a\cdot b \in P$ implies either $a\in P$ or $b\in P$. Then we say $P$ is prime. 
I hadn't noticed that this definition could be generalized to the product of ideals. I hadn't realized that, so i felt it was tricky. Most members like you, have good grasp of mathematics, so these facts might remain trivial for them, but for me i need to explore a lot. Thank you any way.

Comment: Dear @User101 : Thanks for following up :) I was guessing that was your difficulty. I'm glad you discovered the equivalence, because it is very useful. That definition of "prime" is the one used for noncommutative rings as well. For noncommutative rings, it is not equivalent to the elementwise definition. Regards